# Einstein Analytics : Responsive Dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

Is it possible to make the dashboard responsive while clicking on cell in a values table?

For Example I have 10 charts in a dashboard.Among that one is a value table.While doing a click on a particular cell in value table ,based on the selected value can we make the other charts responsive.

Comment: Were you able achieve this. If yes, would you be able to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Click on the widget in edit mode. Then on the right side select 'Query'. There you have to select single or multi selection as Selection Type.
Also make sure "Broadcast selections as facets" is activated.

edit: In compare tables you select a row, while in pivot tables you select a single cell.